# creating single LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for multi module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Our main project pom uses dependent jars which are also developed using Spring application.

we are facing a problem, the dependent jars also contains entities. we would like to create only one LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean at the end which stores all entity in the project(main project and dependent).

I did some reading and tried to implement the following way but without success,

1> Using MergingPersistenceUnitManager in the parent project:
   Issue: When I checked the source code of the class it expects persistence.xml file in the dependent jars. But we don't use persistence.xml, we just use annotation for the same.

2> Creating BeanPostProcessor for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and setting ((LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean)bean).setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors() in postProcessBeforeInitialization method.
 Issue: we have multiple modules so if I code like this only last module PersistenceUnitPostProcessors will be set.

Could some one please help if there is any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Kitty

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to handle this.
In the bean post processor I can add PersistenceUnitPostProcessor by providing package name to be scanned in the respective project.

In the dependent project there should not be any bean created for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean .